# DataGrip only executing first 19 lines of SQL query

Tags: google-bigquery, datagrip

I'm attempting to execute a 236 line query in DataGrip in an attached BigQuery console. When I select the whole script to run, it always only executes up to the 19th line. Because of that, I get this error

```
[HY000][100032] [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Syntax error: Unexpected end of script at [19:49] com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: Syntax error: Unexpected end of script at [19:49]
```

I've tried running it as a SQL file as well, but that resulted in the same error. I Know that this query is valid because it returns the desired results when I run it directly in the Google Cloud query editor. Has anyone else run into this issue, and is there a fix?

Comment: It occurs to me like your query is somehow truncated to 19 lines. I'm not familiar with DataGrip though. Could you prepend lots of comments in the begining the make the whole query having only 1 valid line and to see if you prepend enough comments you will get an error like "empty query"?

Comment: @koko could you attach a sample to reproduce the issue?

If you can't share query in public you can create a private issue in [DataGrip bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE)

Comment: @VasiliiChernov after messing around more with it today, turns out the problem is that the wrong SQL dialect was selected for the query! I had it as Standard SQL, but it has to be BigQuery.

Comment: @koko, yes, it affects parsing dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

We introduced BigQuery dialect recently and it does not apply to your previously created data source after update, since this data source was created with custom driver with 'Generic' dialect as default. It is needed to change dialect in driver options, then you'll have all related consoles and datasources with correct one.